# Where does unetbootin put the downloaded iso files?

Tags: debian, unetbootin

I ran out of space in the root partition in Linux, because Unetbootin puts the ISO files it downloads into the root partition instead of /home, because it runs as root. Now I need to remove the ISO files, but I don't know where it put them.

Answer (score 3):

After searching a bit, I found the ISO file at /tmp. Now I have some disk space and programs aren't failing to run anymore.

Comment: yes! Note: the file name is not same with the operating system name. use the time and date to make sure the corresponding operating system